# Reset in dijit.form.FilteringSelect hitting URL in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have FilteringSelect and dojox.data.QueryReadStore as store.  when i do reset on select filtering drop down it hitting server. `dijit.byId("enquirerOrInstitution").reset();`. What is the reason behind this and how can we stop it? I Have to use FilteringSelect and not ComboBox. Code as below:

```
<td>
<div id="accountList" dojoType="dojox.data.QueryReadStore" jsId="accountListStore" 
                    url="<%=contextPath %>/<%=servlet%>?cmd_search_gcs_account_list=1"></div>
            <select id="gcsAccountNumber" name="gcsAccountNumber" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"
                style="width: 250px" searchAttr="accountNumber" autoComplete="false" pageSize="10" store="accountListStore"> 
</select>
</td>
```

and reset somewhere in JS `dijit.byId("gcsAccountNumber").reset();`.

At this movement, I see a call to server.

Comment: Why you are doing a reset when the select filtering drop down ?

Comment: I Have 4 filtering selects, based on others value i have to reset. First one changed, have to reset remaining 3. I have to select 3rd on basis of 2nd, and on selection of 3rd one I have to populate 4th one. And independently, I need to populate the data on page load. ( functional requirement).

Comment: so for example you want to change the second selecdtfilter based on the first selectfilter selection ? if yes why you want to reset ? why not just query for values you want ?

Comment: On Selection of 1st, I am loading 2nd. But in mean time 3rd and 4th I need to reset. On selection of 2nd, I am loading 3rd. I do not want to keep the old data here as Many to many relationships there. If I don't reset, User may continue with old values in 3rd & 4th drop down which is wrong. I need to follow from bottom-up as well. I desperately required reset. Please help me.

Comment: So don't reset the filterselect because this will just reset the whole thing (With the store), try and reset the store you are using manipulate the data inside the store.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an easy way out:

```
dijit.byId('gcsAccountNumber').removeOption(
       dijit.byId('gcsAccountNumber').getOptions()
);
```

Test if it does send request to your server.

If it does, the routine of removing inner children of the  DOM Element whould give a fair result. Don't worry about having relationships hanging on the dijit, as it will reset once you update its contents. The real memory is held in your store (which is also attempted reset with `.reset()` call)

```
while (node.firstChild) node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. It says no function identified "removeOption" in dojo.

Comment: The thing is, filteringselect based on a store is most likely 'Stateful', which means every manipulation on the view (dropdown) notifies the model (prly forest variant in your case).. The model will then register the object in the store as 'dirty' and subsequent send a request (your reset call) to server saying to delete the items in question.

Comment: If you want a read-only-store (meaning the items dont change based on the users selections), consider destroying (not reset which is stateful) the FilteringSelect programatically, reinsert and re-construct a brand new FilteringSelect (may need to call dom.create to make a new placeholder) in its place with new filter